# Docker, How to synchronize local files with remote container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, synchronization, volumes

How do you synchronize local files with remote container?

What I want to do is change source code on local computer and want to synchronize with remote container.

So that I can test code on remote container.

I used `volumes` to mount local files to the container when I execute `docker compose up`

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./code:/var/www/code
    networks:
      - backnet
    expose:
      - 80

networks:
  backnet:
    driver: bridge
```

But after deployed using `docker compose up`, the folder under `/var/www/code` on remote container `web` does not synchronized after local code changed.

Please let me know how to accomplish this.

Thanks

Comment: Why would changing files on local update them on remote as well? You need to push the changes to remote for this to happen, or change the files on remote location itself.

Answer (score 0):

Docker volumes have no way to transfer data between hosts.  If you build an image, the build context is transferred across the Docker socket, so that can run remotely, but volumes and bind mounts are always interpreted as on the same host where the (remote) Docker daemon is running.

A setup that should work here is to

1. Delete the `volumes:` that hide the image's code;
2. `docker-compose build` a new image when you change local code;
3. Then run `docker-compose up -d` to recreate the container and run your integration test.

Both containers and remote systems can introduce some trouble when trying to do live development.  I'd also make sure I have a good local non-container development environment and write dependency-free unit tests as well as I can.  That helps build confidence my code will actually run, before I go and push it to the remote host.